# Wordpress URL with date structure

Tags: wordpress, facebook, url, permalinks

I've recently had to change the URL structure of a Wordpress blog site from /YYYY/MM/post_name to /post_name
And we are now encountering an issue with lost Facebook comments and like counts.

One thing I figure I could do is pass the Facebook comment script a modified URL that is in the old structure for posts older than X date (before the change)

Is there a Wordpress function to get the permalink in a specific URL structure, or to pass it a structure to get the desired old URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the permalink structure by calling on the `set_permalink_structure()` method of the global `$wp_rewrite` object.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/' );
} );
```